# My Firefox add-on won't show when I install it

Tags: firefox-addon

So, I'm utterly and completely new to making Firefox add-ons. I have been trying to make a really, *really* simple one which will run some JavaScript on the page when I click it. That's literally all I want it to do -_-
However, it will install when I drag it into FF/Nightly, but then not show up in the customise menu. It will say it's installed, but that's it. (I also can't open its preferences, but, I'm really not complaining - I just want a really basic add-on).

If you need the code/entire XPI itself, I'm happy to supply. Thank you :)

I am using the following directories and files:

```
.
├── chrome
│   ├── chrome.manifest
│   ├── content
│   │   ├── boustrophedonise.js
│   │   ├── browser.xul
│   │   └── prefrences.xul
│   ├── locale
│   │   └── en-UK
│   │       └── translations.dtd
│   └── skin
│       ├── icon.png
│       └── skin.css
├── defaults
│   └── preferences
│       └── pref.js
└── install.rdf
```

Comment: Please upload the contents of your XPI to Github and share the link. To get the contents of the XPI, rename it to a zip file then extract the contents, then upload to Github. Do you know if you made a jpm addon? Webextensions addon? Classic bootstrap addon?

Comment: I'll have to get a github account, now! It's a bootstrapless xpi, with the contents zipped as an XPI. I did say that the addon is added, and the description comes up in Firefox, etc.

Comment: Here we are (it was a good excuse to learn how to use git) https://github.com/phunanon/boustrophedonise

Comment: Very nice I'll check it out in a couple hours, I'm a little busy with something.

Answer (score 0):

While there may be other problems, your [*chrome.manifest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration) file is in the wrong directory.  It needs to be in the root directory (the same directory as the *install.rdf* file). This is covered in both the "[Setting Up the Development Environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension#Setting_Up_the_Development_Environment)" and "[Create a Chrome Manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension#Create_a_Chrome_Manifest)" sections of the [Building an extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension) tutorial on MDN. The first section explains that you should start with a directory structure that looks like:

```
.
├── chrome
│   └── content
│       └── sample.xul (Much of your content in this directory)
├── chrome.manifest
└── install.rdf
```

The *chrome.manifest* file is one of the required files for a Firefox add-on.  It defines what URLs like `chome://myExtension/content/*` point to. In your case, without the *chrome.manifest* file being in the root directory, the URL in your *install.rdf* of `chrome://boustrophedonise/content/options.xul` is invalid and is probably complained about in the Firefox [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) when the extension is installed (or perhaps when the add-on manager is displayed, or the link for your add-on options is clicked). Firefox probably also complains about the lack of a *chrome.manifest* file. Obviously, since Firefox is unable to find the *chrome.manifest* file it does not apply the `overlay` onto `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`, nor the `skin`, both of which are defined in that file, which are the things that hook your add-on into Firefox.

So in your case, you need to move the *chrome.manifest* file such that it is located as:

```
.
├── chrome
│   ├── content
│   │   ├── boustrophedonise.js
│   │   ├── browser.xul
│   │   └── prefrences.xul
│   ├── locale
│   │   └── en-UK
│   │       └── translations.dtd
│   └── skin
│       ├── icon.png
│       └── skin.css
├── chrome.manifest
├── defaults
│   └── preferences
│       └── pref.js
└── install.rdf
```

Comment: Damn, I already had my chrome.manifest in the root directory in the first couple times I tried it, and then some random article/tutorial made me put in in the chrome directory. I've moved it, now, but it still does not show up in the browser anywhere but the addons list. Thank you for your explanations, too :)